# clearInerval and setInterval setup not working

Tags: javascript

```
 function dm() { (js code) }

 function lm() { (js code) }


 if (document.body.style.backgroundColor === "black") {
    var lol = setInterval(dm, 20);
    clearInterval(lol2);
  }
  else {
    var lol2 = setInterval(lm, 20);
    clearInterval(lol);
  }
```

Anyone know why this setup isn’t working? Whenever I try it, both the intervals just keep running no matter what.

Comment: How is this code called? Is it in a function or does it run when the page loads? What do `dm` and `lm` do?

Comment: It is just run, nothing special

Comment: Well, then let's say the body has a background color that is `black`. Then `var lol = setInterval(dm, 20);` is called and the `dm` function is called every 20ms. Now how would the interval ever stop? None of the other code in the `if`  statement, like `clearInterval(lol);`,  is ever called. So your interval will go on forever. Unless the `if` statement is somehow called again and another check is performed to see if the interval should stop or not. Could you elaborate more on what you're trying to do. Maybe you have the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: where you are clearing lol or lol2 interval?  This code will execute 1 time and will create infinite intervals. Clear your concept on variable scoping and read about recursive function.

Comment: Assuming that the background color is set inline with `style="background-color:black";`, `lol` will run forever because there's nothing telling it to stop. If the background isn't black (or set via a class or JS), then `lol2` will run forever, but for the same reason. Why would you expect anything different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you have the rgb written correctly in the IF statement when using getComputedStyle.

You can see from the console log that it returns a rgb value.

```js
let dm = () => { console.log("dm") }
let lm = () => { console.log("lm") }
let bg = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
let computed = getComputedStyle(bg);
let style = computed.backgroundColor;
 console.log(style)

function background(style) {
 if (style === "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
    setInterval(dm, 2000);
    clearInterval(1)
  }
  else {
    setInterval(lm, 2000);
    clearInterval(2)
  }
}
background(style);

//this is just to show how changing the background and calling the function again set and clears intervals
setTimeout(function setOrange() {
  bg.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  background();
}, 5000)
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: If `style === "rgb(0, 0, 0)"` evaluates to `true`, then `setInterval(dm, 2000);` will be called. The question is: how will that interval be stopped when that `if` statement is never evaluated again? Same goes for the `else` statement.

Comment: Try console logging `console.log(setInterval(dm, 2000));` then the number that is return put that into you `clearInterval(x)`

Comment: Sure, I'm aware of how it works. But your solution isn't doing that. `dm` and `lm` are references to the functions, not references to the timeouts.

Comment: Here’s the pen I’m working on. Open the console and it will show “dm” twice at which point I change the BG to orange and it switches to “lm” and clears “dm”. https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/vYgwvzw?editors=1112

Comment: FYI: [`document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) is really bad coding and should not be used.

Answer (score -2):

- That's not working because `document.body.style.backgroundColor` not return a value so you can't compare it you need to use `getComputedStyle()` method which will return the body style in `rgb()`
- Example

```
if(window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue("background-color") === "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
    var lol = setInterval(dm, 20);
    clearInterval(lol2);
  }
  else {
    var lol2 = setInterval(lm, 20);
    clearInterval(lol);
  }
```

Comment: Still, even `document.body.style.backgroundColor` would not return anything, the code in the `else` statement would run starting `var lol2 = setInterval(lm, 20);`. The issue of being able to call `clearInterval(lol2)` still persists.

Comment: Can't understand ? What i mean in the comment that your condition isn't working because there's no value to compare it are you tried the example ?

Comment: If you tried it and not working try to explain what happened better to understand you

Comment: `document.body.style.backgroundColor` will return a value if the `background-color` is set with an inline style.

Comment: And FYI: `window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue("background-color")` can be written simply as: `getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundColor`

Comment: OK. There's nothing else i can help you with